# Update a picture contained in a JLabel after a half a second

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, imageicon

I want to create a simple animation of a wolf running. To do so i have 9 png of a wolf's running movement. When the start_button is pressed, it will display all the swing elements of the screen. Then when the wolf_run button is pressed, i want the JLabel wolf to change its icon to "wolf2.png", "wolf3.png", wolf4.png", upto "wolf9.png" and then back to "wolf1.png". This will have a 0.5 second interval between them. The wait() function and everything else works except the changing of the image in the JLabel. I have tried many ways but nothing seem to help. If i do it manually without the wait() function, then it works. But i need the JLabel to change simultaneously as the program runs. Please help me to change the image during execution.
Thank you

PS: i have used a JFrame form to design and implement the GUI in the program

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class page2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
static int i =2;

public page2() {
  initComponents();
  text_field.setVisible(false);
  wolf.setVisible(false);
  wolf_run.setVisible(false);
  jPanel.setVisible(false);
  jPanel.setOpaque(false);

}

public void wait(int a){
long b = (long)a;
Calendar za = Calendar.getInstance();
long t1 = za.getTimeInMillis();
  while (true) {
     Calendar zb = Calendar.getInstance();
long t2 = zb.getTimeInMillis();
if((t2==(t1+b))||(t2==(t1+b-1))||(t2==(t1+a+1))){
break;
}
}
}

private void initComponents() {

    start_button = new javax.swing.JButton();
    text_field = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    wolf_run = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    wolf = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    background2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(849, 499));
    setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(850, 500));
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    start_button.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/button_start.png"))); // NOI18N
    start_button.setToolTipText("click this button to start");
    start_button.setBorder(null);
    start_button.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    start_button.setName("");
    start_button.setPressedIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/button_start_go.png"))); // NOI18N
    start_button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            start_buttonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(start_button);
    start_button.setBounds(290, 80, 310, 310);

    text_field.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Grande", 0, 22)); // NOI18N
    text_field.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
    text_field.setToolTipText("Type here");
    text_field.setFocusCycleRoot(true);
    getContentPane().add(text_field);
    text_field.setBounds(370, 390, 450, 60);

    wolf_run.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
    wolf_run.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            wolf_runActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(wolf_run);
    wolf_run.setBounds(630, 120, 190, 140);

    wolf.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/wolf1.png"))); // NOI18N
    jPanel.add(wolf);

    getContentPane().add(jPanel);
    jPanel.setBounds(20, 320, 330, 150);

    background2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/backgroung2.png"))); // NOI18N
    getContentPane().add(background2);
    background2.setBounds(0, 0, 850, 500);
    getContentPane().add(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setBounds(10, 320, 310, 160);

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void start_buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
Calendar za = Calendar.getInstance();
  int m1 = za.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
  int s1 = za.get(Calendar.SECOND);
  while (true) {
     Calendar zb = Calendar.getInstance();
     int m2 = zb.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
     int s2 = zb.get(Calendar.SECOND);
     if (m2 != m1) {
        s2 = s2 + 60;
     }
     if (s2 == s1 + 1) {
        start_button.setVisible(false);
        start_button.setEnabled(false);
        text_field.setVisible(true);
        wolf.setVisible(true);
        wolf_run.setVisible(true);
        jPanel.setVisible(true);
        break;
     }
  }
  }                                            

private void wolf_runActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
while(true){
wait(500);
        wolf.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/wolf"+i+".png")));
 System.out.println("processing "+i);
i=i+1;
if(i>9)
{   i=1;}
}
}                                        

public static void main(String args[]) {
  try {
     for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
           javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
           break;
        }
     }
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
     java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(page2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
     java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(page2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
     java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(page2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
     java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(page2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }

  java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

     public void run() {
        new page2().setVisible(true);
     }
  });


}

private javax.swing.JLabel background2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JButton start_button;
private javax.swing.JTextField text_field;
private static javax.swing.JLabel wolf;
private javax.swing.JButton wolf_run;

}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25092903/java-applet-thread-animation/25092949#25092949) for an example using swing timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `javax.swing.Timer`.

See the Java tutorial [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 1):

Use [javax.swingTimer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). Waitnig in Swing Event thread causes a GUI freeze